# Laravel 5.5 y Vue.js: metodo post trae "query_string"

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

Por alguna razon, mis métodos post generan un elemento llamado "query_string".

En Laravel pido lo siguiente:

```
Route::prefix('api/workers')->group(function (){
    Route::post('create', 'WorkersController@createWorker');
});
```

Y en Vue.js mando con axios así:

```
axios.post("api/workers/create", this.data).then(res => {
        this.$toasted.show("Trabajador creado", { position: "bottom- 
        center", duration: 2500 });
        this.$router.push("/");
  });
```

En el metodo de laravel hago un retorno con $req->all() ($req es el request), y me trae lo siguiente:

"query_string" => null

No entiendo por qué trae el query_string, pero sé que no es normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema tal vez este en la ruta a la cual estas enviando el post con el axios

> axios.post("api/workers/create", this.data)

yo creo que el problema es la ruta debes de colocar colocar al principio /api

de debe de quedar mas o menos asi

> axios.post("/api/workers/create", this.data)...

debes de colocar el / por que si no se lo colocas la ruta nunca la va a conseguir